# How should the ViewModel refer to its Models properties?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

As the ViewModel has the job to "prepare" the Model's properties to get displayed in the View, what is the best way of referring to the underlying Models properties from the ViewModel?

I could think about two solutions by now:

---

### Option 1 - Duplicate the Model's properties in the ViewModel (wrapper-approach)

**Architecture**

```cs
class Model
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public int p2 { get; set; }
}

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Model-instance for this ViewModel
    private Model M;

    public string p1 
    {
        get { return M.p1; }
        set 
        { 
            M.p1 = value; 
            // assuming View controls are bound to the ViewModel's properties 
            RaisePropertyChanged("p1");  
        }
    }

    // let's say, I only want to check a Checkbox in the View,
    // if the value of p2 exceeds 10.
    // Raising the property changed notification would get handled
    // in the modifying code instead of the missing setter of this property.
    public bool p2
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (M.p2 > 10)
            { return true; }
            else
            { return false; }
        }
    }

    // Initialize the Model of the ViewModel instance in its c'tor
    public ViewModel()
    { M = new Model(); }
}
```

**Binding**

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding p1}"/>
<Checkbox IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding p2, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**Advantages**

- Full control about how the Model's properties are displayed on the View as shown in *p2*: *int* gets converted to *bool* on demand.
- Changes of the properties of the ViewModel could be raised individual, might be a little performance increase compared to option 2.

**Disadvantages**

- Violation of [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).
- More Code to write/maintain.
- Modifications to the Model/ViewModel could easily become [shotgun surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_surgery).

---

### Option 2 - Treat the whole Model as property of the ViewModel

**Architecture**

```
class Model
{
    public string p1 { get; set; }
    public int p2 { get; set; }
}

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Model instance for this ViewModel (private field with public property)
    private Model _M;
    public Model M 
    { 
       get { return _M; }
       set 
       {
           _M = value;
           // Raising the changing notification for the WHOLE Model-instance.
           // This should cause ALL bound View-controls to update their values,
           // even if only a single property actually got changed
           RaisePropertyChanged("M");
       } 
    }

    // Initialize the Model of the ViewModel instance in its ctor
    public ViewModel()
    { M = new Model(); }
}
```

**Binding**

```
<Textbox Text="{Binding M.p1}"/>
<Checkbox IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding M.p2, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}"/>
```

**Advantages**

- Can save a lot of code.
- Reduces complexity.
- Increases maintainability.

**Disadvantages**

- In this approach, the ViewModel is nothing more than a continuous-flow water heater for the Models properties, except for some possible interaction logic for the View.
- No control about how the Model's properties are displayed in the View - which ultimately leads to total needlessness of the ViewModel and implementation of conversion logic in the View.

Comment: why isn't the type Model the one that is treated as a ViewModel ? Why not have it itself inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged ?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity. The code shown is of course not able to run and only serving the understanding of the general question: How to expose the data inside the Model via a ViewModel? Poperty-cloning or declaring an instance of the Model as bindable property? Or some completely different approach?

Comment: Also have a look at http://blog.alner.net/archive/2010/02/09/mvvm-to-wrap-or-not-to-wrap.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the useful link, that is a well written and straight-to-the-point article! :-) 

As I was thinking, I'm not the first person ever to face this issue.

Comment: @RicoSuter The author says : " The second option is simpler and seems more pragmatic. It says “I’ll add properties on the VM where they are needed, but I’m not trying to control all access to the model.” " I think he's wrong, your ViewModel ONLY contains what you need to display in your View.

Comment: As always: I think it depends. It's always a question whether this decoupling is needed or more rapid development / pragmatic approach is needed...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is the responsibility of your **ViewModel** to expose the **Model** to the **View**, you should not expose the Model's properties as additional properties in the ViewModel, instead, your View should bind directly to the model.

Additionally, it isn't *wrong* to have logic in your **Model**, in fact, it makes more sense to contain model related code within the model, as opposed to the ViewModel.

Here is an example:

```
public class Movie
{
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;

            //Notify property changed stuff (if required)

            //This is obviously a stupid example, but the idea
            //is to contain model related logic inside the model.
            //It makes more sense inside the model.
            MyFavourite = value == "My Movie";
        }
    }

    private bool _MyFavourite;

    public bool MyFavourite
    {
        get { return _MyFavourite; }
        set
        {
            _MyFavourite = value;

            //Notify property changed stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

So to answer your question a little more directly, you should expose your model in the view model as a **property**.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private Movie _Model;

    public Movie Model
    {
        get { return _Model; }
        set 
        { 
            _Model = value;

            //Property changed stuff (if required)
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Therefore, your View will bind to the `Model` property, like you have already done so.

EDIT

In the example for casting to the type, you can implement a read-only property in your Model, like so:

```
public bool MyBool
{
    get 
    { 
        return MyInt > 10; }
    }
}
```

Now the magic here would be that you will need to call the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for this property whenever `MyInt` changes. So your other property would look something like this:

```
public int MyInt
{
   get { ... }
   set 
   {
       _MyInt = value;

       //Notify property changed for the read-only property too.
       OnPropertyChanged();
       OnPropertyChanged("MyBool");
   }
}
```

Comment: So, basically, you encourage the use of **Option #2**. But why would I need a ViewModel at all, if it's only purpose is to show an instance of the Model to the View? Also, the problem of the missing preparation of the Models propertys (eg. type conversion, see the *M.p2* example in the *advantages* section of Option #1) remains unsolved in this attempt.

Comment: Yes, **Option #2** is the way to go. The general usage requires the view to be bound to a view model, where the view model exposes the model, this doesn't mean that in some (very rare) cases, you would not need a view model, in which case you can simply bind directly to a model. Remember, MVVM is a pattern, **not the law**. In regards to type conversion, there's nothing stopping you from creating a **read-only property** (A property with just a `get`) in the Model, this will allow you to keep the logic contained within the model. **Or**, you can use a converter, as you have done.

Comment: +1 for pointing out **a pattern isn't a law**. I tend to forget this sometimes, as I'm convinced that learning never stops. ;-)
As for the ReadOnly-property within the Model, wouldn't this just be an implementation of a prepared ViewModel-property inside the Model? Seems even more mixed up to me...
I personally try to avoid converters in the View by now, as imho the view should get everything delivered ready-to-display to keep the dependencies between View and ViewModel at a minimum.

Comment: I have edited my answer to help explain how to achieve the read-only property functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and everything that you say makes sense to me. It is too much dupicated code if you repeat all your properties again inside the VM. However I have a problem with my project and I don't know how to solve it. Would you mind taking a look at it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50863997/wpf-bind-to-class-doesnt-call-setter
@MikeEason

Comment: Basically I wanna fire a event, when the property of a class has changed. How do I achieve that when I bind to a class?

Comment: I'm very confused because as far as I can tell this answer violates the whole premise of MVVM. The ViewModel is supposed to *hide* the model, right?! I get that a pattern isn't law, but the question is explicitly about how to follow the pattern, so shouldn't the correct answer actually explain how to follow the pattern?

Comment: I have to agree with @LeMotJuiced here. Let's say for example, I have a service that fetches my domain objects from an external service and presents the data as IEnumerable<MyModel>. I don't want it to know where it's used for, infact in most cases, it can't know, because the model sits in a seperate library with no references to WPF (or any other view). So in an ideal scenario the Model should only contain data. The ViewModel then decides what part of the model is presented to the View and contains view specific logic e.g. the property for the checkbox.

Comment: Look at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123317/should-we-bind-view-to-a-model-property-or-viewmodel-should-have-its-own and https://docs.catelproject.com/vnext/introduction/mvvm/different-interpretations-of-mvvm/

Answer (score 2):

In my view, *Model* should not have *RaisePropertyChanged* stuff. Some view models (e.g. Blazor) might not need it, others (e.g. WPF) might use other mechanisms like `DependencyProperty`. Thus, to me *Model* is a POCO class. Hence, it becomes *ViewModel* responsibility to report changes to the data up to the *View*. Consequently, *ViewModel* is bound to wrap *Model*'s properties (OA's option 1).

You might want to look at *AutoMapper* to centralize the mappings.